# How to use javascript map to combine numbers at every nth element?

Tags: javascript, array-map, nth-element

I like to combine numbers at every 4th index of an array.  In the following oversimplified example, I did using "for" loop.  Instead of that, I like to learn how to use "map" to achieve the same result.  Thanks for any help!

```
function test() {
  var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], arrayNew = [];
  for (var n = 0; n < 4; ++n)
    arrayNew[n] = array[n] + array[n + 4];
  console.log(arrayNew)
}
```

Comment: Is your code correct? Is that what you mean with "combine"?

Comment: What is your expected output for an array of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` ?

Comment: Why should this be done with `.map()`? Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Mapping is a 1:1 operation, so the result will be the same length as the input. This could be achieved with `.map()` but through jumping through hoops that are artificially imposed.

Comment: To avoid confusing with adding elements, I stated "combine", which I know incorrect.   My expected results is 1+5=6, 2+6=7, ....   I saw the beauty of "map" can be written in one line, which can help in some complex lines of codes.

Comment: That doesn't fully answer the original question though: given the input you're showing, what is the output you expected here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `.map`, you could iterate the slice of the array that omits the first four elements. During that iteration, the loop index will be 4 units less, so you can grab `array[i]` and combine it with the currently iterated value from the slice:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const result = array.slice(4).map((val, i) => array[i] + val);
console.log(result);
```

If you want to add more than just two values, but want to also add the value at 2n, 3n, ...etc, then you need a *nested* loop. Here `.map` is of less use. I would "map" with the use of `Array.from`, which has a callback function that performs a mapping. Secondly, the sum that has a dynamic number of terms can be performed with `reduce`:

```js
function accumulate(array, n) {
    const groups = Array.from({length: array.length / n});
    return Array.from({length: n}, (val, i) => 
        groups.reduce((sum, _, j) => sum + array[i + j*n], 0)
    );
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
console.log(accumulate(array, 4));
```

Comment: one more favor please to expand skills!  The example had 8 elements.  What if the array has 12 elements?

Comment: Then what is the output you expect? If there is any change in the "step" (what you call `n`), then just change the `slice(4)` to `slice(n)` where `n` is the step you have in mind. If `n` somehow relates to the length of the array, then please clarify that.

Comment: In the 12 elements array, if I want 1+5+9=15, 2+6+10=18, ... every 4th elements

Comment: Ah, in your question there was a hardcoded sum of **two** values only. I have added a section to my answer. Let me know if this is what you were looking for?